# AutoCompleteTextView - prevent dropdown from closing while calling notifyDataSetChanged

Tags: android

I'm using my own `Adapter` and my own `Filter` to populate `AutoCompleteTextView`. Everything works fine except that every time when I'm calling `notifyDataSetChanged` dropdown with is closed and then reopens again with new suggestions (which is kind a annoying).

What I'm trying to achieve - is the same behaviour as Google. When you typing word, dropdown just populated with new values (without reopening). Is there any workarounds?

**PS**

Adapter populated in `Filter#publishResults`:

```
@Override
protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
    if(results == null) {
        return;
    }

    mAdapter.clear(); //notifyDataSetChanged is NOT called here

    List<?> content = (List<?>) results.values;
    final int size = content.size();
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++) {
        mAdapter.add((City) content.get(i));
    }

    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```